# Setting a button value to contain an ampersand coded character via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set a button value to be « (or ») via JavaScript with the following code:

```
document.getElementById('hideButton').value='&laquo;';
```

This just sets the button text to `&laquo;` rather than «.

The HTML markup works fine (i.e. `<input type="button" value="&laquo;">`) giving the double left arrow quote on the button face.

Is there some special way of escaping the ampersand code in JavaScript?

Thanks,

FM

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in the question... I've added the extra ; in the question but it was already in my code.

Comment: you want to set some text for button face?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

here just convert to UTF it should work.

```
document.getElementById('hideButton').value='\u00AB';
document.getElementById('otherButton').value='\u00BB';
```

here a link to [convert](http://www.rapidmonkey.com/unicodeconverter/) special text

Comment: That's got it! And a unicode approach seems to be a safe option for cross-browser compatability.

Answer (score 2):

couldn't you just do this?

```
document.getElementById("hideButton").value = "«";
```

Sorry I would have just commented, but haven't got enough rep yet.

Alternatively, use the unicode `\u00AB`

http://jsfiddle.net/s53FH/

Answer (score 0):

you could use the -element instead

```
<button id="hideButton"> </button>
<script>
    document.getElementById('hideButton').innerHTML='&laquo;';
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6m3zz/

Comment: He uses the `<input />` tag, not the `<button>`. This wouldn't work with `input`.